# Play framework - guarantee a thread local gets cleared at end of request or beginning of next request

Tags: java, playframework, thread-local, playframework-1.x

We are using a thread local in play to provide a sort of "first level cache" for the WS (web service) library so that calls to the same URI within a given request only happen once.  Currently I'm using an @Before filter to ensure that before any given request starts we clear anything in the thread local since play seems to keep a pool of them around.

Is there any better way to implement this than having to do @With(MyThreadLocalKillingFilter.class) on our base controller? It works but seems hackish.

Note that we're using plays built in server starting with play start/run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing hackish using @With this way in you controller. I think this is fairly common. It is considered better practice than extending a base controller.

You might want to be careful with using ThreadLocals though, specially if using promises which suspends the request execution thread.

Comment: I just hate that you have to remember to do it.  It's a cross cutting concern that should not have to be on every controller. Also realizing the potential issues using ThreadLocals I wonder how the framework itself is dealing with that as it uses ThreadLocals all over the place for request, session etc.